# Wildcard in params matcher

Tags: kubernetes, prometheus, prometheus-operator

I am trying to create a service monitor which scraps all the datas of a specific namespace. My ServiceMonitor looks like this :

```
---
apiVersion: monitoring.coreos.com/v1
kind: ServiceMonitor
metadata:
  labels:
    serviceapp: api-servicemonitor
  name: servicemonitor-federate
  namespace: NS
spec:
  endpoints:
  - interval: 15s
    port: http
    path: /federate
    honorLabels: true
    params:
      match[]:
      - '{__name__=~".+",namespace="NS"}'
      ....
```

But this regexp doesn't look like to be correct : the datas are not scraped and sent to my prometheus

Any ideas on how to make a viable regex when specifying the namespace ?

Regards,
Guillaume

Comment: Why didn't you specify spec.selector? It's required field.

Comment: the code snippet is partial : tahts why its not displayed on the topic

Comment: no one ? :(
id really need the syntax on the match : how to '*' for a given namespace...
Guillaume